# What brand of bar tape does Raleigh use on brand new bikes?

Tags: road-bike, handlebar-tape

I really liked the bar tape my bike came with, but I don't know what kind it was. It has a distinctive texture and a sort of tacky feel to it. Would like to find the same bar tape again. My bike is a Raleigh Capri 2.0, purchased in July 2012.

The possibilities I've found that look similar are:

[Avenir Textured Gel Tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BDRGT6)

[PRO Digital Carbon Tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FU9H18)

Comment: Most likely its something generic that they get at the factory or if it is sold under a name brand, its likely Avenir. I'd take the tape into a shop and see if you can find something similar.

Comment: I don't have the tape anymore. I unwittingly threw it out last time I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Raleigh sells components and accessories by various brands including its own *Raleigh Special Products* RSP line.

http://www.raleigh.co.uk/ProductType/?pc=2&pt=297

Comment: good to know! My bike's original bar tape does not appear to be there though.